# mySQL Query Caching symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony

How can i Cache MySQL Query 24 Hours in Text Files when using symfony ?

I dont want to Cache the Rest just MySQL , because of whitelabeling.

Is there any warpet Or Similar ?

I already Researched the Results on google but did Not find result.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony alone does not have any functionality for query/resuts caching, [but doctrine does](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html). There's some convenience in using Symfony along that - enabling doctrine cache can be done by config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    result_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
```

Obviously every query results/parameters have to be saved manually, these options only enable that.

Comment: Further reading: [Symfony's Doctrine Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) - [Caching Tips Slides](http://fr.slideshare.net/liuggio/rationally-boost-your-symfony2-application-with-caching-tips-and-monitoring) - [Doctrine Cache Library](https://github.com/doctrine/cache)